# python how do i use my string in a for loop

Tags: python

i have a few strings that hold a value. i.e.
how can i loop though multiple string1,string2,string3 etc?

```
string1 = re.findall('qr="">(.*?)</span', str(raw[1]))
string2 = re.findall('qr="">(.*?)</span', str(raw[2]))
string3 = re.findall('qr="">(.*?)</span', str(raw[3]))

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

i would like for it to print the value of string1,string2,string3

i have tried to store string1 - string3 in a list but with ut success.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Try using a list: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: all you would need is to put all of the strings into a list, then loop through them.

Comment: It appears that you need more practice on loops and lists, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this perhaps

```
strings = []

string1 = re.findall('qr="">(.*?)</span', str(raw[1]))
string2 = re.findall('qr="">(.*?)</span', str(raw[2]))
string3 = re.findall('qr="">(.*?)</span', str(raw[3]))
strings.append(string1)
strings.append(string2)
strings.append(string3)


for i in strings:
    print(i)
```